# Java: Get super class from an anonymous class

Tags: java, superclass, anonymous-class

In Java, I use an anonymous class inside a class A which extends B. How can I access to B from this anonymous class? I can't use the keyword `super`, because this means *super class of the anonymous class*, not *super class of A*.

```
public class A {

    void foo() {
        System.out.println("Good");
    }
}

public class B extends A {

    void bar() {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                foo(); // Bad: this call B.foo(), not A.foo()
                // super.foo(); // Bad: "Method foo is undefined for type Object"
            }

        };
        r.run();
    }

    @Override
    void foo() {
        System.out.println("Bad");
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt that you can do this, given that the class only has a *reference* to a `B`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please call as fallows:

`B.super.foo();`

After this change `B` class looks as follows:

```
public class B extends A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B().bar();
    }

    void bar() {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                B.super.foo(); // this calls A.foo()
            }

        };
        r.run();
    }

    @Override
    void foo() {
        System.out.println("Bad");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In `run`, you could change `foo()` to `B.super.foo();` when I changed that and then ran `B.bar()` I get `Good`.

Answer (score 2):

In such a case, you need to qualify `this` to capture the outer class, `B`

```
B.this.foo()
```

Or, in your case, as you want the super class, use

```
B.super.foo()
```

Relevant parts of Java Language Spec:

- [Qualified `this`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4)
- [Accessing superclass members with `super`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.2)

Comment: That executes the "Bad" method.

Comment: Ahh, missed that. Fixed